# Apply function to every column in data frame operating on names

Tags: r, plyr, apply

I'm trying to write something that will take a data frame and plot every numeric column, with simple plots for non-normal distributions and control charts for normal ones:

```
library(plyr)
library(qcc)
library(ggplot2)

#generate data frame
data <- data.frame(seq_len(10),LETTERS[seq_len(10)],rnorm(10,5,3),rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rnorm(10,3,1),runif(10))

##checks heterogeneity
has_range <- function(data) { if(all( abs(data - mean(data)) == 0)) FALSE else TRUE}

##test for normality
normtest <- function(data) {if(has_range(data) == FALSE) FALSE else {
  if(shapiro.test(data)$p.value < 0.05) FALSE else TRUE}}

##Control charts for Normal data, simple plots otherwise
drawplot<-function(data, ref=NULL) {
  Sys.sleep(.1)
  print(names(data))
  if(normtest(data) == FALSE) {
    plot(x=ref, y=data, ylab=names(data))
  } else {
    qcc(data,type="xbar.one", labels=ref, ylab=names(data))  
  }
}

## Apply drawplot to all numeric columns in data frame
colwise(drawplot, is.numeric, ref=data[[2]])(data)
```

The problem is that every apply family function seems to strip column names and I can't use the column names to label the plots:

```
print(names(data))
```

Gives NULL results.

Also there's a seemingly unrelated error that is cropping up:

```
Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a function that uses the names, otherwise the names won't be accessible within the function.

You can't pass `x = NULL` to `plot`, so I've rewritten a bit of your function
(`qcc` was kicking up a fuss with an atomic vector for `x` as well)

Something like

```
drawplot<-function(n, data, ref=NULL) {
  Sys.sleep(.1)
  print(n)


  if(normtest(data[[n]]) == FALSE) {
    if(is.null(ref)){ref <- seq_along(data[[n]])}
    plot(x=ref, y=data[[n]], ylab=n)
  } else {
    qcc(data[,n, drop=FALSE], type="xbar.one", labels=ref,ylab = n)  
  }
}

lapply(names(Filter(is.numeric,dd)), drawplot, data = dd)
```

Note that this function would work with position indexing as well (but the labels wouldn't be as pretty)

Comment: Thanks mnel, this seems to work. Just a note to anyone reproducing, you have to name the original data frame you create to 'dd' in this modification. Now I'm going to pretty up the graphs and see if I can use ggplot2 instead of plot. Also, it would be nice to have a ggplot2 based qcc package.

Comment: @variable -- yes, I'd renamed. I don't like `data` as a variable name, as there is a function `data`.